# Alert with a textarea content (HTML to JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new at coding with any language and now im working (trying to) with HTML, PHP and JavaScript. My difficulty is to show through an alert in a JavaScript file the information that is in a textarea from an HTML file. The HTML code is this:

```
    <head>
        <title> My Form</title>
        <script type= "text/javascript" src ="./JavaScript/validaLinha.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="Linhas" method="POST" action="Linhas-p.php">
             <textarea name="descricaoLinha" onFocus="resetField('descricaoLinha')"> TEXT-TEXT-TEXT</textarea>
        </form>
    </body>
```

As you can see at the HTML code, I try to send the name of the textarea to a JavaScript function called "resetField". Let's see what the "resetField" does:

```
function resetField(field){
    d = document.Linhas;

    alert("It's entering the function."); //ANSWER = It's entering the function.
    alert(field);                         //ANSWER = descricaoLinha
    alert(d.field.value);                 //ANSWER = Nothing.
    alert(d.getElementById(field).value); //ANSWER = Nothing.
}
```

I can't get the information set at the value of my textarea! The event is calling the function (First alert shows up), the string is being received by the function (Second alert shows the name of the text area) but the other two that are the ones that i need doesn't show up. I already tried to change the order of the alerts because of that JavaScript stuff that doesn't continues to read the code if an error appears.

Just to emphasize, i want the content IN the textarea. (The name of it is being received properly)

Thanks for reading! Sorry about my english. ^^

Comment: try with d.descricaoLinha.value

Comment: Can you post this on fiddle? Can't replicate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'field' is just a string, not a javascript object and of course it does not have the `name` attribute;

And it is similar to the `d = document.linha;`

You have have to get the DOM element by its `id` attribute:

d = document.getElementById("Linha");

---

**Edit: You also need add the id attribute to your field**

```
<textarea id="descricaoLinha" name="descricaoLinha" onFocus="resetField('descricaoLinha')"> ...
```

One solution is: you change your JavaScript function to

```
function resetField(fieldId) {
    var field = document.getElementById(fieldId);
    alert(field);           // object
    alert(field.value);     // text field value    
    // Do whatever you want with the field object here 
}
```

You should turn on the console and using `console.log('output')` instead of using `alert()` for debugging;
You can turn on Firefox console by <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + K</kbd>

Comment: In-Browser debuggers have such lovely features these days, you can look at complex objects and get cross references to really trace back your scripts. I'm 100% with @simpleton, `alert` is no way to debug a script!

Answer (score 5):

Add an `ID` to your textaea

```
<textarea id="descricaoLinha" name="descricaoLinha" onFocus="resetField('descricaoLinha')"> TEXT-TEXT-TEXT</textarea>
```

And then, send the `ID` **instead** of `name`

```
alert(d.getElementById(field).value);
```

This code can't find the element *descricaoLinha* because its searching for an element that has an **ID** = "*descricaoLinha*"

Comment: Your explanation of why it doesn’t work isn’t quite right. `d.field.value` is looking for the element with the name of `field`, not the `id` of `descricaoLinha`; `d[field].value` would work. But yes, an `id` is probably better, and not using inline handler-attributes would be best.

Comment: @minitech I didn't explained why `d.field.value` doesn't work. I just explained why `d.getElementById(field)` didn't worked..And its because of the ID right? :)

Comment: I tried it @JudeDuran, but it did not worked. The alert with the textarea content did not showed up. The solution that minitech gave worked here. I still dont know why Hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in `this` in your `onfocus` handler:

```
onFocus="resetField(this);"
```

Access it like:

```
alert("It's entering the function."); 
alert(field.name);                       
alert(field.value);
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RbUZr/